# OpenCV 3.2 MOG2->apply - failed assertion

Tags: c++, image, opencv, video-capture

I implement my own subtractor on the tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/video/background_subtraction/background_subtraction.html

My code:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    const std::string filename = "/home/yurychu/my_video.avi";
    VideoCapture capture(filename);

    Mat frame;
    Ptr<BackgroundSubtractor> pMOG;
    pMOG = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();

    namedWindow("FG mask MOG 2");

    while (1) {
        if (!capture.read(frame)) {
            cerr << "Unable to read next frame. Exiting..." << endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        Mat fgMaskMOG2;
        pMOG->apply(frame, fgMaskMOG2);

        imshow("FG mask MOG 2", fgMaskMOG2);
        waitKey(33);
    }

    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

But after running my program I get this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (clEnqueueReadBuffer(q, (cl_mem)u->handle, CL_TRUE, 0, u->size, alignedPtr.getAlignedPtr(), 0, 0, 0) == CL_SUCCESS) in map, file /home/yurychu/developing/opencv/modules/core/src/ocl.cpp, line 3674
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/yurychu/developing/opencv/modules/core/src/ocl.cpp:3674: error: (-215) clEnqueueReadBuffer(q, (cl_mem)u->handle, CL_TRUE, 0, u->size, alignedPtr.getAlignedPtr(), 0, 0, 0) == CL_SUCCESS in function map
```

And if I comment this lines - She disappears.

```
//pMOG->apply(frame, fgMaskMOG2);
//imshow("FG mask MOG 2", fgMaskMOG2);
```

Where could I make a mistake?

Comment: Try to declare `Ptr<BackgroundSubtractorMOG2> pMOG;`. I think in your code, `pMOG` is a pointer to `BackgroundSubtractor` whose method `apply` is not implemented.

Comment: Your code actually works on my machine. Have you tried @QuangHoang suggestion?

Comment: @QuangHoang [`apply` is virtual], and `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` derives from `BackgroundSubtractor`. He holds it in a smart pointer, so why wouldn't that work?

Comment: @YuryChu This looks a bit suspect. Can you reproduce it without the video? (e.g. just use `cv::Mat::zeros` instead) What platform is this on? What compiler? Did you build the library yourself? Give us details, please.

Comment: Sorry, problem solved in system terminal compilation with cmake, not in IDE. Ubuntu 16.04. gcc 5.4.0 OpenCV 3.2 building from source, with contrib modules and CUDA. Now all work fine.